# Limit redo for materialized view complete refresh or manual equivalent

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, materialized-view

A materialized view<sup>(MV)</sup> log can be used to allow a MV to do a fast refresh which only modifies the data that has changed.  However, various conditions prevent the MV from using the log and therefore require a complete refresh.  Oracle implemented an atomic complete refresh as a delete and insert of every record.  It does this even if there are ultimately no changes to the data.

Is there a way to make this replication intelligent *with regard to redo generation*?  A MERGE followed by a DELETE requires querying the source twice.  Would it be worth it to bulk collect the data to do a BULK MERGE and DELETE?  Is there a better way?

Update:

I explored using a global temporary table as a staging area.  Although they use less than half the redo, they still use to much.

Comment: Can you post the gtt code? gtt's don't generate redo directly, but they do generate undo - and undo generates redo. `insert` ops generate much less undo than `delete` or `update` ops (almost none in fact). Having multiple gtts to avoid any expensive ops might be a good approach

Comment: @Jack Douglas http://psoug.org/reference/gtt.html has a GTT Redo Generation Demo showing a 60% reduction in redo between a physical table and a GTT for `insert`s.  This closely matches the results I am seeing and is better but not as good as I would like.

Comment: Those tests (row-by-row and no `append` hint) are not ideal conditions for reducing redo - I've run some tests to show what I mean. Posted as an answer because they won't fit in a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just intended to demonstrate redo usage of various `insert` operations rather than answer the whole question. Results on my 10g instance are not 100% deterministic, but the broad picture remained the same each time I ran through.

For the heap tables, I do not know why the `insert /*+ append */` generated more redo.

testbed:

```
create table heap_noappend(id integer, dummy char(500));
create table heap_append(id integer, dummy char(500));
create global temporary table gtt_noappend(id integer, dummy char(500));
create global temporary table gtt_append(id integer, dummy char(500));
create global temporary table gtt_results(stage integer, val integer);
```

test:

```
insert into gtt_results(stage, val)
select 0, value from v$statname join v$sesstat using(statistic#)
where sid=sys_context('userenv','sid') and name='redo size';

insert into heap_noappend(id, dummy)
select level, 'A' from dual connect by level<1000;

insert into gtt_results(stage, val)
select 1, value from v$statname join v$sesstat using(statistic#)
where sid=sys_context('userenv','sid') and name='redo size';

insert /*+ append */ into heap_append(id, dummy)
select level, 'A' from dual connect by level<1000;

insert into gtt_results(stage, val)
select 2, value from v$statname join v$sesstat using(statistic#)
where sid=sys_context('userenv','sid') and name='redo size';

insert into gtt_noappend(id, dummy)
select level, 'A' from dual connect by level<1000;

insert into gtt_results(stage, val)
select 3, value from v$statname join v$sesstat using(statistic#)
where sid=sys_context('userenv','sid') and name='redo size';

insert /*+ append */ into gtt_append(id, dummy)
select level, 'A' from dual connect by level<1000;

insert into gtt_results(stage, val)
select 4, value from v$statname join v$sesstat using(statistic#)
where sid=sys_context('userenv','sid') and name='redo size';
```

result:

```
select * 
from( select decode(stage,1,'heap noappend',
                          2,'heap append',
                          3,'gtt noappend',
                          4,'gtt append') as operation, 
             val-lag(val) over(order by stage) as redo 
      from gtt_results)
where redo is not null;

OPERATION     REDO                   
------------- ---------------------- 
heap noappend 606932                 
heap append   690768                 
gtt noappend  41488                  
gtt append    256
```

Comment: You are correct of course.  I should have caught that in their tests.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

Good question. I "solved" this problem for my situation a while back by making the MV's and any indexes on them NOLOGGING. There was no point to it my situation - I was doing a full refresh of the view anyway, why would I need redo?

Comment: You may [need ATOMIC_REFRESH=false](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:616795500346622064) too (on 10g and above). Not sure what the implications are for any standby database or recovery with archive logs?

Comment: I run a logical and a physical standby on the database I did this with. No issues there. I did run into an issue with making DB copies - have to look at my notes but there was an error I would sometimes get about performing recovery on a tablespace with nologging tables. I've read recommendations to create a tablespace reserved for tables/indexes that are nonlogging to avoid such issues. I did figure out how to solve it though.

Comment: @Jack, I believe I did have to use non atomic refresh.

Comment: Hmmm, if I use a standard materialized view, it needs to do an atomic refresh, so this won't work for me.  Someone else may find it useful, so it is still a good answer.

Comment: Why does it need an atomic refresh? As I understand it, setting that to false only affects a FULL refresh. See this asktom post: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:616795500346622064

Comment: As it turns out, the problem I was having with the error on DB copies was due to an index on the MV that was not set to NOLOGGING.

Comment: You are correct that setting atomic refresh to false only affects a FULL refresh, but since a FULL/COMPLETE refresh is being done, setting it to false would unacceptably limit data availability.